# Ubuntu 16 - Holding Volume Up key on keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, volume-control, indicator-sound

I'm trying to change the volume level on my Ubuntu 16.

If I try to mute via holding the notebook's "Fn" + "volume down" key, the volume decreases 1 level and then it quickly decreases the rest of it, as expected.

If I try via USB Keyboard (I have a [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012)) holding the volume down button, it only decreases one level. That means I have to press it over and over until the volume is muted. Same thing happens with Volume Up key.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but here's some info from [a Mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Notes): When you press a key, the keyboard sends three signals: keydown, keypress, and keyup. As long as the key is held down, keydown and keypress should keep repeating. In this case, the keyboard or its driver might not be repeating properly.

Comment: Whoops, the above only applies to Firefox. I just ran `xev | grep "^Key" -A5` and saw the actual signals that Linux has are just called "KeyPress" and "KeyRelease", and they both repeat while the key is held down.